# Hessian of a vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold with Levi-Civita connection $\nabla$. For a scalar function $f$, one has the Hessian formula
\begin{equation*}
\nabla^2f(X,Y) = \nabla_{X}\nabla_{Y}f - \nabla_{\nabla_{X}Y}f
\end{equation*}
I'm wondering whether there is a similar formula for $D_{\alpha}D_{\beta}U^{\gamma}$ where $U$ is a vector field and $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are indices of an arbitrary frame? I'm interpreting the expression as the $\gamma$ component of the vector field $\nabla^2U(e_\alpha,e_\beta)$, but was told that
\begin{equation*}
D_{\alpha}D_{\beta}U^{\gamma} = (D_{\alpha}(D_{\beta}U))^{\gamma} - (D_{D_{\alpha}\beta}U)^{\gamma}
\end{equation*}
is not true.

Comment: Yes, the Hessian of a vector field $X$, written $\nabla^2X$, is the tensor that brings $Y,Z$ to $\nabla^2_{Y,Z}X = \nabla_Y \nabla_Z X - \nabla_{\nabla_YZ}X$. Same thing for the Hessian of general tensors $\nabla^2 T$.